Accessing a Google Storage encrypted object without informing headers
I have many objects in my Google Storage bucket that are encrypted with a customer-provided encryption key. To access each file, I have to inform these 3 headers (I have the key):

x-goog-encryption-algorithm
x-goog-encryption-key
x-goog-encryption-key-sha256

Although I can provide my clients with access to the keys, most of them are not able to create an script that can submit headers in the request. They mostly just want to click an URL and get the file.
Is there any way so I can inform those parameters in the URL, so passing it as extra headers is not required? I checked the signed_url methods from the official libs, and they have a header parameter, but it does not work.
